# Adding a JSDoc return type for a function that creates a dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there a way to use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started) with plain JavaScript (not TypeScript) to define the return type for a function like this, which creates a new class as output that's an extension of a user-provided class provided as function input?

```js
/**
 * Build a new class that extends the UserProvidedClass, and return that.
 * @param {class} UserProvidedClass
 * @returns ???
 */
function createClientClass(UserProvidedClass) {
  return class ClientClass extends UserProvidedClass {
    // this class will not have an explicit constructor.
    bindServerSocket(socket) {
      this.server = socket;
      this.onConnect();
    }
    onConnect() {
      super.onConnect?.();
      if (DEBUG) console.log(`client connected`);
    }  
  };
}

// And then an example of how this gets used:

class CustomClass {
  // this class will also not have an explicit constructor.
  testServer() {
    console.log(`instance has server:`, !!this.server);
  }
}

const ClientClass = createClientClass(CustomClass);

// Typing-aware editors and tooling should now know that
// this instance has three methods on it:
const instance = new ClientClass();

// And things like VS Code should be able to see that the following
// function is from the class inside "createClientClass":
instance.bindServerSocket(new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:800`));

// And that the following function is from "CustomClass":
instance.testServer();
```

The following technically "works" in that the typing isn't strictly speaking wrong, but will of course not contain any of the dynamic class's methods and fields that aren't in the UserProvidedClass:

```js
/**
 * We are strictly speaking returning an instance of UserProvidedClass
 * here, but by typing it as such, all the methods added by the extension
 * will be lost.
 *
 * @param {class} UserProvidedClass
 * @returns {UserProvidedClass} 
 */
function createClientClass(UserProvidedClass) {
  return class ClientClass extends UserProvidedClass {
    bindServerSocket(socket) {
      this.server = socket;
      this.onConnect();
    }
    onConnect() {
      super.onConnect?.();
      if (DEBUG) console.log(`client connected`);
    }  
    ...
  };
}

// instance type hints will not show `bindServerSocket` or `onConnect`
```

The alternative seems even more problematic: if we pull out the dynamic class as a real class, then we run into inheritance problems because JS does not allow multiple inheritance on classes:

```js
class BaseClass {
    bindServerSocket(socket) {
      this.server = socket;
      this.onConnect();
    }
    onConnect() {
      super.onConnect?.();
      if (DEBUG) console.log(`client connected`);
    }
    ...
}

/**
 * @param {class} UserProvidedClass
 * @returns {T extends BaseClass, UserProvidedClass} JS cannot do this
 */
function createClientClass(UserProvidedClass) {
  return class ClientClass extends ??? {
    // We can't extend both the BaseClass and the UserProvidedClass.
  };
}
```

Is this one of those things that JSDoc just can't do, or is there a JSDoc way to do what TS does with types and interfaces, without having to write "no-op" JS that captures the methods and properties of some class without ever getting used for anything other than type docs?

As suggested, I read the docs on [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [templates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template), but either I'm skipping over something or this isn't covered by the examples given, because with templates all I can come up with that yields a return type in the type hinting is:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @template { bindServerSocket(socket:WebSocket):void,onConnect():void } U
 * @param {T} UserProvidedClass
 * @returns {V implements U extends T}
 */
function createClientClass(UserProvidedClass) {
  return class ClientClass extends UserProvidedClass {
    bindServerSocket(socket) {
      this.server = socket;
      this.onConnect();
    }
    onConnect() {
      super.onConnect?.();
      console.log(`connected`);
    }
  };
}

const ClientClass = createClientClass(
  class {
    test() {
      console.log(`test`);
    }
  }
);

const instance = new ClientClass();
instance.bindServerSocket(new WebSocket(`http://localhost`));
instance.test();
```

Where the return type for the function is now flagged as `implements U extends T` with the typing hint for `ClientClass` being `ClientClass`, and while `bindServerSocket` resolves to the dynamic class method, `test` does not resolve to the method of the class that was passed into the function.

(The same happens with `@return {U extends T}`, where the typing can resolve functions from U, but not from T)

Comment: It seems like you want to make this _generic_, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template. Then the return type is the union of the input and the additional methods.

Comment: That won't capture the methods and properties of the dynamic extension itself though, will it? That will just make it return "whatever `UserClientClass` was during the call", rather than the union.

Comment: That's going to depend on how exactly you use it, if you have a more specific problem give a [mre] _of that_.

Comment: This is the exact example. The function is passed a class (which can be anything, including just `class{}`) and it returns a new class that's an extension of that passed-in class, with a bunch more methods and properties. The problem is how to write JSDoc that will mark the return type as a class that has all properties and methods of both (with type tooling able to jump to definitions in the correct place).

Comment: And you do that, express a relationship between input and output types, using generics (see e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html if you're unfamiliar). In JSDoc, that's represented with a `@template`. If you've had a problem _applying that_, which is not in what you've posted, show it.

Comment: fair enough: edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to not officially be possible due to there not being any official JSDoc syntax for indicating that a parameter or return is for "an actual class definition" rather than for "an instance of some class".

There are a number of issues about this on [the JSDoc issue tracker](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues), with the most appropriate appearing to be issue 1349, ["Document class types/constructor types"](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1349), filed in 2017, which has not been resolved as of the time of this post in late 2023.

See Julio's answer for a possible approach, but note that there do not appear to be any official or even unofficial docs for the typing tricks used, and so that may or may not work for you depending on when you find this post, or the tooling you're using.

(VS Code with the source marked as TypeScript to maximize type-awareness, for instance, can tell that `instance.bindServerSocket()` is defined in the `createClientClass` function, but cannot tell that `instance.test()` is defined in `CustomClass`)

Answer (score 0):

The return type can only be properly defined if `ClientClass`, or a corresponding `typedef` (the equivalent of an interface), is *not* hidden inside `createClientClass`.

Below is some code, simply using a `typedef`, that seems to do the trick (tested at playcode.io).  Also, you had a error in your code: `createClientClass` returns a constructor, not an instance.

By the way, I find your construction a bit "suspect", but I don't know your actual design requirements, and I have only replied to your direct question.

```js
/**
 * Represents the 'ClientClass' component of
 * the return type of {@link createClientClass}.
 * 
 * @typedef IClientClass
 * @type {object}
 * @property {(socket: string) => void} bindServerSocket
 */

/**
 * Returns a class of type {@link IClientClass} that
 * extends the given {@link UserProvidedClass}.
 * 
 * @template {class} T
 * @param {abstract new () => T} UserProvidedClass
 * @returns {new () => IClientClass & T}
 */
function createClientClass(UserProvidedClass) {
  return class ClientClass extends UserProvidedClass {
    bindServerSocket(socket) {
      this.server = socket;
    }
  };
}

// And then an example of how this gets used:

class CustomClass {
  testServer() {
    console.log(`instance has server:`, !!this.server);
  }
}

// create the constructor
const clientClass = createClientClass(CustomClass);

// create an instance
const clientInstance = new clientClass();

// check methods are visible
clientInstance.bindServerSocket("1");
clientInstance.testServer();
```

A side note about "reputable sources": it is not even possible here to link to the reference documentation since 1) the JSDoc reference documentation is minimal to say the least and in fact not at all exhaustive; moreover, 2) most tooling actually leverages TypeScript for parsing JSDoc typing annotations and checking code, so results are not strictly determined by JSDoc anyway, results here are more of a half way between what JSDoc is supposed to offer and the support that TS engines actually give to typing annotations.  And none of that is properly documented anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

```js
/**
 * Creates a new class that extends the given base class. The new class
 * will have additional methods 'bindServerSocket' and 'onConnect'.
 *
 * @template T - The base class to extend.
 * @param {new(...args: any[]) => T} UserProvidedClass - The class to be extended.
 * @returns {new(...args: any[]) => T & ClientClassMethods} - A new class that extends the UserProvidedClass and adds new methods.
 */
function createClientClass(UserProvidedClass) {
  return class ClientClass extends UserProvidedClass {
    bindServerSocket(socket) {
      this.server = socket;
      this.onConnect();
    }
    onConnect() {
      super.onConnect?.();
      if (DEBUG) console.log(`client connected`);
    }
  };
}

/**
 * This is a helper type that defines additional methods added by ClientClass.
 * @typedef {Object} ClientClassMethods
 * @property {Function} bindServerSocket - Method to bind a server socket.
 * @property {Function} onConnect - Method called on connection.
 */

// Usage Example:
const instance = createClientClass(CustomClass);
instance.bindServerSocket(new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000'));
instance.testServer();
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer so that it shows off what you describe with "_Then, you can use the `@extends` keyword followed by the name of the template parameter (`T`) to indicate that the returned class should extend the specified base class_"? Because that's the core of the question, so right now this post isn't an answer yet, it's still missing part of the JSDoc for this function. Also note this is explicitly _not_ TypeScript: this is plain JS with JSDoc comments, so there is no tsconfig, there's no `type` or `interface` keyword, etc. It's just pure JS, and typing through comments.

Comment: (Also note that [the format for `@returns` _has_ to include the type information](https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns). If it's not `@returns {returnTypehere} and then the description`, it's not a JSDoct return type hint; the format you're using in your answer does not include the actual typing the question asks for)

Comment: Yes Definitely I update my answer.